# Redirect URL not working in IONIC app from google drive and dropbox

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, capacitor, ionic-native

Able to login into google account but after that instead of redirect to the google drive files it is showing **loader** and in dropbox able to login and see the files in dropbox but when I am choosing the files it gives me the error. Both google drive and dropbox screenshot are attached.

[Dropbox error- Could not communicate with the http://localhost:8100](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQHD8.png)
[Google Driver error- It keeps showing the loader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Rdub.png)

Comment: Can you show some code first? You probably have to add your localhost:8100 to your 'whitelist'. Also some errors/warnings that you get in the logs will help